# is it true to do this to malloc array with unknown size

Tags: c

I want to make an array with unknown size , is it true to make it like this ? :

```
int *array,var,i=0;
FILE *fp;
fopen=("/home/inputFile.txt","r");
fscanf(fp,"%d",&var);
while(fp!=NULL)
{
    if(var>0)
   {
        array=malloc(sizeof(int));
        array[i++]=var
   }
   fscanf(fp,"%d",&var);
}
```

Comment: Not to do this, The index is out of boundary causing UB or SEGV.

Comment: *`I want to make an array with unknown size`* -- No , arrays are static data-structure

Comment: Your could would not even compile as is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is absurdly false, full of memory leaks and undefined behaviors.

However, it's not *that* far from one of the right ways, the linked list way:

```
struct linked_int
{
    int value;
    struct linked_int* pNext;
};

struct linked_int *pHead=NULL;
struct linked_int **ppTail = &pHead;
int* array = NULL;
int cpt=0;
/*Read file, building linked list*/
FILE *fp = fopen("/home/inputFile.txt","r");
if(fp != NULL)
{
    int var;
    while(fscanf(fp,"%d",&var)==1)
    {
        if(var>0)
        {
            struct linked_int *pNew = malloc(sizeof(struct linked_int));
            pNew->value = var;
            pNew->pNext = NULL;
            /*Append at the tail of the list*/
            *ppTail = pNew;
            ppTail = &(pNew->pNext);

            cpt++;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

/*Copy from the linked list to an array*/
array = malloc(sizeof(int) * cpt);
if(array != NULL)
{
    int i;
    struct linked_int const *pCur = pHead;
    for(i=0 ; i<cpt ; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = pCur->value;
        pCur = pCur->pNext;
    }
}

/*Free the linked list*/
while(pHead != NULL)
{
    struct linked_int *pDelete = pHead;
    pHead = pHead->pNext;
    free(pDelete);
}
ppTail = &pHead;
```

**Other ways:**

Another right way is the `realloc` way, which consists in re-allocating the array with an ever expanding size (usually with a geometric growth, i.e. multiplying the array size by a number such as 1.5 every time). A *wrong* way to do so is to add 1 to the array size every time.

It goes something like this:

```
int arrayCapacity=0, numberOfItems=0;
int* array = NULL;
int var;
while(fscanf(fp, "%d", &var)==1)
{
    if(numberOfItems >= arrayCapacity)
    {
        /*Need to resize array before inserting*/
        const int MIN_CAPACITY = 4;
        const double GROWTH_RATE = 1.5;
        int newCapacity = arrayCapacity<MIN_CAPACITY ? MIN_CAPACITY : (int)(arrayCapacity*GROWTH_RATE);
        int* tmp = realloc(array, newCapacity*sizeof(int));
        if(tmp==NULL)
        {
            /*FAIL: can't make the array bigger!*/
        }
        else
        {
            /*Successfully resized the array.*/
            array = tmp;
            arrayCapacity = newCapacity;
        }
    }

    if(numberOfItems >= arrayCapacity)
    {
        puts("Cannot add, array is full and can't be enlarged.");
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        array[numberOfItems] = var;
        numberOfItems++;
    }
}
/*Now we have our array with all integers in it*/
```

The obvious result is that in this code, there can be unused space in the array. This isn't a problem.

Comment: I got your idea and now it is working very good ,thank you .but can you  explain more about realloc ,please ?

Answer (score 1):

sizeof(int) will return you 4 (and note that few compilers/settings may say you 2 or 8 in response). So your code is equivalent to allocating a 4 bytes long array.

If you want an array with unknown size, it could be worth to take a loot at STL containers like std::vector (because it will manage allocations and resizes behind the scene). If you plan to stick with "plain C" scope, you may be interested with TSTL2CL library: http://sourceforge.net/projects/tstl2cl

Comment: As i remeber exaclty therefore we have malloc/ realloc.

Answer (score 1):

The basic thing is, ARRAY is STATIC not DYNAMIC.

Comment: Once defined via malloc it is array with static size. As long not allocated, it is simply no array, is it ?